# Uploading multiple excel files using Sharepy to Sharepoint

Tags: python, sharepoint

I am trying to create a python script that imports files from a desktop folder to a Sharepoint sites folder.

I am using Sharepy to perform this task.

This is the script I have currently:

```
import sharepy
import os
import glob

s = sharepy.connect("https://xxx.sharepoint.com", username='xxx@xxx.com', password='xxx')

filesToUpload = (glob.glob("C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/xxx/*.xlsx"))

for fileToUpload in filesToUpload:
            headers = {"accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/x-www-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"}

            with open(fileToUpload, 'rb') as read_file:
                content = read_file.read()

            p = s.post(f"https://xxx.sharepoint.com/xxx/yyy/_api/web\
            /GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/xxx/yyy/Shared Documents/zzz/aaa/')/Files/add(url='fileToUpload',overwrite=true)", data=content, headers=headers)
```

It works fine when I do it one at a time but not with this loop. I have about 5 xlsx excel sheets in my folder currently.

How can I upload multiple files with a single request?

Answer (score 3):

Can you try to put the files to import into a list which you will loop over?

Try this :

```
import os
import glob

s = sharepy.connect("https://xxx.sharepoint.com", username='xxx@xxx.com', password='xxx')

filesToUpload = [f for f in glob.glob("*.txt")]   #New line

for fileToUpload in filesToUpload:
            headers = {"accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/x-www-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"}

            with open(fileToUpload, 'rb') as read_file:
                content = read_file.read()

            p = s.post(f"https://xxx.sharepoint.com/xxx/yyy/_api/web\
            /GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/xxx/yyy/Shared Documents/zzz/aaa/')/Files/add(url='fileToUpload',overwrite=true)", data=content, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Can you show an example of this method in code?

Comment: If my code does the job, mark my solution